# How to make the dates on an Excel 2016 scatter plot start today?

Tags: excel, scatter

How can I make the date on the x-axis, start from
today?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The textbox which is labelled 'Minimum' contains a date number, but you can simply type in eg "1 Jan 2020" if you want and excel will convert it to the correct date number.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But how about just starting today?

Comment: You want it to use a different value if you refresh the graph tomorrow or next month? In Excel VBA you can set the Chart.Axis.MinimumScale property and you could update that on a daily basis, but through the normal user interface you can only give it a static value.